# Windows 11 won't start after uninstalling Intel RST driver

Tags: windows, boot, bios, windows-11, intel-rst

While trying to create a dual boot, I uninstalled `Intel RST` in the `Device Manager`. Big mistake, now I have a blue screen when booting my Windows 11.

I discovered later that I needed to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in the BIOS to just disable `Optane with RAID` on the SATA mode, like on this picture of documentation: https://us.v-cdn.net/cdn-cgi/image/fit=scale-down,width=1600/https://us.v-cdn.net/6029997/uploads/editor/0o/0qmnwbrlxjdd.jpg

I tried all SATA mode but my Windows still wont start without Intel RST driver..
I reinstalled Windows 11 on another partition to try to recover the main one, but I don't know what to do.
Is it possible to reinstall `Intel RST` from one Windows 11 to another ?

My pc is an Acer Nitro AN515-55, my config is:
https://www.driverscloud.com/en/configuration/smkrlr7jrk4-1/summary

Comment: At what stage of the boot do you encounter the blue screen? Can you boot into Command Prompt?

Comment: Indeed, Intel RST or similar "RAID" modes managed by the firmware aren't (yet) supported in Linux, reason why everywhere it is said to disable (change drive mode to AHCI) it but also to **install AHCI support in Windows**. If you want to dual-boot that's how it'll have to be. You could've just "repaired" the current Windows installation as that would've installed AHCI support.

Comment: @harrymc I have the choice of the boot between my Windows, and if I select my old Windows, I'm able to go to "repair" and select Command Prompt !

Comment: Download the Intel RST setup as in [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000027232/technologies/intel-rapid-storage-technology-intel-rst.html#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Intel%20Download,file%20to%20install%20the%20driver.), boot to CMD and try to run the installation.

Comment: I tried to do this, and also unzip the .exe and install the .inf using pnputil but nothing works. I don't know if I am on a windows or on the good windows when getting on command prompt. I can get here by letting the PC have a blue screen. Then when it restart, I have `Automatic recovery` > `Advanced options` > `Command Prompt`. But it launch a command prompt on disk `X:` that don't exists normaly. I need to go myself on my disk `E:` then install the drivers, and I think it's not the on any windows..

Comment: If you want a dual-boot with any Windows you **can't have Intel RST enabled** so the question about drivers is moot and doesn't make sense. Again, you need to install AHCI support in order to have a functioning Windows in such dua-boot. If you find this too hard then don't dual-boot and use virtual machines instead.

Comment: Ok, I finaly found a solution !!! using `dism`. I will try to write a nice answer for anyone facing the same problem.

Comment: IF you write an answer make sure to clearly mention that it ISN'T a solution to the actual question - dual-boot - but something else you want to do.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, thank you. But first I wanted to recover my Windows with all my data. Tomorrow I will try to install support for AHCI and create my dual boot. I will replace the "dual-boot" tag for "boot".

Comment: You don't need to do nothing to enable booting from the Windows as it is other than changing the drive mode back to what it was before (and the Windows was originally installed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151190/discussion-between-borhink-and-changanauto).